# Cant get uIAlertAction to work textfield will only read first and last element

Tags: ios, swift

Im doing an IOS contact app and I want the user to able to change there quick information from an alert my problem is that I cannot get my alertAction to read anything beside the first and last element

```
let add = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { _ in
            guard
                let name = alert.textFields?.first?.text,
                let address = alert.textFields?.first?.text,
                let state = alert.textFields?.first?.text,
                let city = alert.textFields?.first?.text,
                let zip = alert.textFields?.first?.text,
                let phoneString=alert.textFields?.last?.text,
                let phone = Int(phoneString)
                else { return }
```

I know that alert.textField?.first.text returns the first element and alert.textField?.last.text returns my last element ,so what ever goes in my name and phone textField is good , but how can I return the elements that go in to my address , state , city and zip text fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `tag` to each of your textFields. And then utilize it, you can enumerate your textFields in your alert object. For example:

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Name", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Name"
        textField.tag = 0
    }

    alert.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Address"
        textField.tag = 1
    }

    alert.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter State"
        textField.tag = 2
    }

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { _ -> Void in
        guard let name = alert.textFields?.filter({ $0.tag == 0 }).first?.text,
            let address = alert.textFields?.filter({ $0.tag == 1 }).first?.text,
            let state = alert.textFields?.filter({ $0.tag == 2 }).first?.text else { return }

        /////
    })

    alert.addAction(saveAction)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

OR

```
        let name = alert.textFields?[0].text ?? ""
        let address = alert.textFields?[1].text ?? ""
        let state = alert.textFields?[2].text ?? ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple textfields inside a UIAlertController. UIAlertController has a property "textFields" which is basically a array of all added TextFields.
You can add a textfield using this code  -

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Hi", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField { (textFieldName) in

        // Configure it here
    }

    alert.addTextField { (textFieldAddress) in

    }

    alert.addTextField { (textfieldCity) in

    }
```

The order in which you add the textFields ,will be same when you will access the textfields using "textField" property.